# cross fading 2 elements to creat a looping animation with no js

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I am wanting to animate an element so it cycles between "0% interest free credit" and "free delivery", I am trying to achieve this with no javascript, but I am only able to get the first element to fade away and not get the second to fade in.

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
}

.parent p {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.parent p:first-child {
  animation: hide 2s ease-in
}

.parent p:last-child {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: show 2s ease-in animation-delay:2s;
}

@keyframes show {
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes hide {
  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <p>0% interest free credit</p>
  <p>free delivery</p>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong I would like 1 fade out as the other fades in, and for it to loop endlessly.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to make sure your animation is set to loop. Use the keyword `infinite` as your [animation-timing-function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-timing-function) for that.

Second, we can restructure your animation to happen in one reusable keyframe sequence that shows and hides the element. By making the whole animation 4 seconds long and offsetting it by half of that (2 seconds) on one element, we achieve a seamless loop of the two elements fading in and out:

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
}

.parent p {
  animation: show 4s infinite;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.parent p:last-child {
  animation-delay: -2s;
}

@keyframes show {
  0%, 50%, 100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  
  10%, 40% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <p>0% interest free credit</p>
  <p>free delivery</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Quick explanation of the keyframe animation sequence here - since we want the animation to be visible half the time and invisible the other half, let's think of 0% through 50% as visible, and 50% through 100% as invisible. However, we also want to have a smooth fade transition, so I chose to leave an extra 10% for fading at the beginning and end of the 'visible' half, hence the keyframes at 10% and 40%.